# Cannot Connect to Gmail

Tags: settings

When I enter in my Gmail credentials it tells me that they are invalid. I do not have have two factor authentication activated on my account. I have tried several times with no luck

Comment: with which application do you want to connect: Network, Calandar, Mail?

Answer (score 1):

Use the instructions [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) or [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-do-i-enable-less-secure-apps-on-gmail/) to enable less secure applications to connect to your Google account. But it is generally encouraged to enable 2FA, and generate passwords on a per app basis.